# foldLeft or foldRight equivalent in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, fold, rdd

In Spark's RDDs and DStreams we have the 'reduce' function for transforming an entire RDD into one element. However the reduce function takes (T,T) => T
However if we want to reduce a List in Scala we can use foldLeft or foldRight which takes type (B)( (B,A) => B) This is very useful because you start folding with a type other then what is in your list.

Is there a way in Spark to do something similar? Where I can start with a value that is of different type then the elements in the RDD itself

Comment: Do note that I updated the answer below. Since I see you are sort of new, do "accept" the answer if it solves your issue to help others looking for unanswered questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [aggregate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) instead of reduce. It allows you also to specify a "zero" value of type B and a function like the one you want: (B,A) => B. Do note that you also need to merge separate aggregations done on separate executors, so a (B, B) => B function is also required.

Alternatively, if you want this aggregation as a side effect, an option is to use an accumulator. In particular, the [accumulable type](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.Accumulable) allows for the result type to be of a different type than the accumulating type.

Also, if you even need to do the same with a key-value RDD, use [aggregateByKey](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions).

Comment: What about for DStreams? there we do not have an 'aggregate' function

Comment: Use `transform` to operate under the underlying RDDs. A DStream is basically a sequence of RDDs.